# MySQL: Duplicate key name on import

Tags: mysql

I have a problem after I made a mysqldump of my database, when I try to re-import it, I get a "Duplicate key name" error.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `et_prevision`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `et_prevision` (
  `pk_prevision` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fk_account` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_nature` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_prevision_level` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_analysis_axis1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_analysis_axis2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_creator` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_modifier` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_reconciliation` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_sicav` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_rate` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_prevision` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fk_funding` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operation_date` date NOT NULL,
  `value_date` date NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` date NOT NULL,
  `modification_date` date NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(14,5) NOT NULL,
  `libelle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `piece_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `commentaire` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reconciliation_libelle` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `monitored` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `operation_count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `is_subscription` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cycling` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cycle_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remittance_reference` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_principal` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sicav_parts_count` decimal(14,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sicav_rate` decimal(14,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investment_margin` decimal(14,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investment_effective_rate` decimal(14,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investment_day_count` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investment_count_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attachment_file_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `investment_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `print_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevision_batch` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fk_interface` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk_prevision`),
  KEY `fk_prev_account` (`fk_account`),
  KEY `fk_prev_nature` (`fk_nature`),
  KEY `fk_prev_prevision_level` (`fk_prevision_level`),
  KEY `fk_prev_analysis_axis1` (`fk_analysis_axis1`),
  KEY `fk_prev_fk_analysis_axis2` (`fk_analysis_axis2`),
  KEY `fk_prev_creator` (`FK_CREATOR`),
  KEY `fk_prev_modifier` (`FK_MODIFIER`),
  KEY `fk_prev_reconciliation` (`fk_reconciliation`),
  KEY `fk_prev_sicav` (`fk_sicav`),
  KEY `fk_prev_rate` (`fk_rate`),
  KEY `fk_prev_prev` (`fk_prevision`),
  KEY `fk_prev_funding` (`fk_funding`),
  KEY `fk_interface_to_interface` (`FK_INTERFACE`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_interface_to_interface` FOREIGN KEY (`FK_INTERFACE`) REFERENCES `et_p_interface` (`pk_interface`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_account` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_account`) REFERENCES `t_account` (`PK_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_analysis_axis1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_analysis_axis1`) REFERENCES `et_p_axe_analyse_2` (`pk_axe_analyse_2`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_creator` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_creator`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`PK_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_fk_analysis_axis2` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_analysis_axis2`) REFERENCES `et_p_axe_analyse_3` (`pk_axe_analyse_3`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_funding` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_funding`) REFERENCES `et_funding` (`pk_funding`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_modifier` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_modifier`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`PK_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_nature` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_nature`) REFERENCES `et_p_nature` (`pk_nature`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_prev` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_prevision`) REFERENCES `et_prevision` (`pk_prevision`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_prevision_level` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_prevision_level`) REFERENCES `et_p_prevision_level` (`pk_prevision_level`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_rate` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_rate`) REFERENCES `et_p_rate` (`pk_rate`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_reconciliation` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_reconciliation`) REFERENCES `et_reconciliation` (`pk_reconciliation`) ON DELETE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_sicav` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_sicav`) REFERENCES `et_p_sicav` (`pk_sicav`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

The error happens on the "fk_prev_creator" key. I am sure I do not have any key with that same name anywhere on the database, and I tried renaming it into "fk_prev_creator1", which gave me the same error. I tried removing the key declaration, and it throws another error on "fk_prev_modifier". If I remove the two key declaration, everything works fine, however, since this dump is supposed to be used for installation purposes, I'd like to know why these to exact keys do not work as intended.

Edit: For your information, both dump and import are made on a server under mysql 5.1.33.

Edit2: I tried to import into a 5.6.X server, and it worked like a charm. So it seems to be related to the MySQL version, but I did not find any bug report about this.

Thank you.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME,
    INDEX_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db' AND INDEX_NAME='fk_prev_creator' ;` Assuming you have the fresh db run this.Does it return anything?

Comment: No result from this.

Comment: What seems strange to me is that mysql allows you to create a table with 2 identical constraints.Here is a test,I expected it to fail http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18b8b Maybe on import mysql wakes up and doesnt allow it.Also maybe you have another table imported which has the same constraint somehwere?

Comment: I have another table on this exact same database where I have two foreign key also to t_user (pk_id), and import on this table works fine. (These constraints do not have the same name as these ones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I finnaly found why the import was not working.
If you look closely at the to KEy de clarations:

```
  KEY `fk_prev_creator` (`FK_CREATOR`),
  KEY `fk_prev_modifier` (`FK_MODIFIER`),
```

They differ a bit from the CONSTRAINTS declarations:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_creator` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_creator`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`PK_ID`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_prev_modifier` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_modifier`) REFERENCES `t_user` (`PK_ID`),
```

The difference is that in the KEY declaration, fields names are in caps, and not in the CONSTRAINT declaration. In 5.1.X, it matters, and not in 5.6.X, so in this case, MySQL saw it as if I was trying to declare another rule, and did not like it.

tl;dr: 5.1.X is case sensitive in this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

When re-importing a database you need to drop the entire database first. Not entirely sure why this is, but I had this very issue a while ago and this is how I fixed it.

If you are running a command, just add this to your `mysqldump`:

```
--add-drop-database
```

Check the [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-database) for this option.

Otherwise, you can edit the entire query, and add this at the very top:

```
/*!40000 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `myDatabase` */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ dbName ......
```

Comment: The import is run on a fresh new database, so the problem does not come from already existing tables.

Comment: But you are re-importing an existing database, right? idk, try it and see what happens.

Comment: No, the I dumped only the tables. There is no 'CREATE DATABASE ....' in the script.

Comment: I understand that. You are exporting all tables of a database, but you aren't creating the database it self. Correct? If yes, try the above anyway. I also wanted to just create the tables and not the entire database, but the above fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Correct. I tried using your code, but I got the exact same error.

Comment: mysqldump -u root --opt dbname --add-drop-database > test.sql

Answer (score 0):

Dropping the target db then recreating it (e.g. mysql -e 'drop database if exists mydb; create database mydb;') worked for me. I had to turn off foreign key contraints, also, then turn them back on at the end of the dump to prevent an error where an FK is declared in a table but its target table wasn't yet created.

Mysql 5.7.29 dump importing to 5.7.27